# Issues calling Oracle stored procedure from C#

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures

This is the first time that I have ever had to call an Oracle stored procedure from C# and I don't know why my code is not working. All that I am trying to do is return a datatable. My stored procedure compiles just fine - here is some pseudocode describing it:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SPROC_ONLINE
( Year IN NUMBER DEFAULT NULL
, Name IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL
, ID IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL
, refCursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
AS
BEGIN
OPEN refCursor FOR
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE Field_Year = Year
  AND Field_Name = Name
  AND Field_ID = ID;  
END SPROC_ONLINE;
```

Here is some pseudocode describing my C#:

```
public static DataTable search(int? Year, string Name, string ID)
    {            
        try
        {
            OracleConnection conn = getConnectionString();                
            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandText = "SPROC_ONLINE";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("Year", OracleDbType.Int32).Value = Year;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("Name", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = Name;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("ID", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = ID;                
            cmd.Parameters.Add("Output", OracleDbType.RefCursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
            getConnectionString().Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            da.Fill(dt);

            return dt;                
        }
        catch (Exception e) { throw new Exception("Error: " + e.Message); }
        finally { getConnectionString().Close(); }
    }
```

No errors are being thrown; it's just that the datatable that is returned is null when it should not be (the parameters that I am testing with should be returning something).

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: That ExecuteNonQuery has no meaning there. Remove it

Comment: Side note: I am not sure what the implementation is inside of `getConnectionString().Close()` but if that returns a static connection that would be bad practice. You generally want to create a new (not shared) database connection object when it is needed and dispose of it when its done. Otherwise you will have problems later on should you ever decide to have more than one thread doing something independently with the database at the same time. Let the database implementation worry about pooling connections (*I believe Oracle can also handle this without much issue*).

Comment: @Igor - Thank you for the suggestion; your comment led me to do some additional research. I've only worked on small applications thus far and I was not aware of this. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue ended up being two-fold; here is the code-behind that I ended up with:

```
public static DataTable search(int? Year, string Name, string ID)
{
    try
    {
        using (var cmd = new OracleCommand("SPROC_ONLINE", getConnectionString()))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            var da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("Year", OracleDbType.Int32).Value = Year;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("Name", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = Name;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("ID", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = ID;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("Output", OracleDbType.RefCursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            return dt;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {throw new Exception("Error: " + e); }
    finally {}
}
```

My other issue was that I did not realize that string comparisons in Oracle were case-sensitive. Apparently between compiling my stored procedure in SQL Developer and trying to test it in Visual Studio, I was not consistently entering the "Name" parameter; this explains why a null datatable would be returned. I adjusted the WHERE clause of my stored procedure as follows:

```
WHERE Field_Year = Year
  AND UPPER(Field_Name) = UPPER(Name)
  AND Field_ID = ID;
```

Everything works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may need to use `OracleDataReader`.

```
using(OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("SPROC_ONLINE", TheConnection))
{
    using(OracleDataReader reader = new OracleDataReader())
    {
        while(reader.Read())
        {
            // Extract the values
            var a = reader["Year"];
            var b = reader["Name"];
            var c = reader["ID"];
            ... etc ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In this case, will I need to dynamically create my datatable inside of the while loop?